# On click of child div having same class as its parent some class should be added to child div not parent div and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html structure.

```
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="someclass"></div>
</div>
```

So when I click on child div "someclass" some other class say "test" should be added to it but that class should not be added to parent div.someclass and if I click on parent div then "test" class should be added to parent div not to child div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.addClass` and use `this` context. `stopPropogation` will not bubblr the event on `parent` element.

```js
$('.someclass').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.someclass').removeClass('test');
  $(this).addClass('test');
})
```

```css
.test {
  color: red!important;
}
.someclass {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass">Parent
  <div class="someclass">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__